# Rolle's theorem in n dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, dg.differential-geometry, geometry

This looks like a statement from a calculus textbook, which perhaps it should be.

"Rolle's theorem". Let $F\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb R^n$ be a continuous function such that $F(a)=F(b)$ and $F'(t)$ exists for all $a<t<b$. Then there exist numbers $a < t_1 < t_2 < \dots < t_n < b$ such that the vectors $F'(t_1),\dots,F'(t_{n})$ are linearly dependent.

We are all familiar with the case $n=1$. The case $n=2$ is not hard either: pick any $a<t^\ast<b$ and find, using the mean value theorem, numbers $a<t_1<t^\ast$ and $t^*<t_2<b$ such that $F'(t_j)$ is collinear with $F(t^\ast)-F(a)$. Note that we avoided using the parameter value $t^\ast$, which will be important in a moment. When $n=3$, we pick $a<t^\ast<b$ and project F onto the orthogonal complement of $F'(t^\ast)$, then apply the case $n=2$ to the projection ($t^\ast$ will become the third chosen parameter value). So far so good.

But I get stuck at $n=4$. If the above process is followed, then after $F$ is projected down to two dimensions, we must avoid two particular parameter values. Which is not possible in general: if in two dimensions $F$ parametrizes a triangle and $F(a)$ is a vertex, then one of points $F(t_j)$ must be one of two other vertices. Presumably this problem can avoided by a generic choice of points of projection, but how?

Comment: Harry, your link is to the case when the domain is R^n, not the range.  They mention an inequality that does extend to higher dimensional ranges, but they don't appear to address Leonid's question.

Comment: @Harry: so you are using the method of proof by irrelevance? :P

Comment: Mariano, isn't that the best kind of proof? ;)  I deleted my comments to make room for the other comments, but in summary, I posted a link to a proof of the MVT for R^n, but it was irrelevant.

Comment: I think I can solve the original problem for even $n$. Interested?

Comment: Okay, please wait a few more minutes... I think I've now solved the general case. BUT I need an additional condition: the function $F$ should be continuously differentiable (not just differentiable), and the derivatives at the endpoints should match as well.

Comment: Added differential geometry and geometry tags. Something tells me this has more to do with geometry than with real analysis.

Comment: Okay, as long as my solution below stays incomplete, I'm giving the fix for even $n$: Read my reply until (4), and notice that, whenever $\left(t_1,t_2,...,t_n\right)$ is an $n$-tuple of points in counterclockwise position, then so is $\left(t_n,t_1,t_2,...,t_{n-1}\right)$, so (4) yields that the reals $\det\left(F^{\prime}\left(t_1\right),F^{\prime}\left(t_2\right),...,F^{\prime}\left(t_n\right)\right)$ and $\det\left(F^{\prime}\left(t_n\right),F^{\prime}\left(t_1\right),F^{\prime}\left(t_2\right),...,F^{\prime}\left(t_{n-1}\right)\right)$ have the same sign, which is absurd.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a solution in the $C^1$ case [but see upd]. Suppose the vectors $F'(t_1),\ldots, F'(t_n)$ are linearly independent for all $0\leq t_1< \cdots < t_n\leq 1$. Let $L(t_1,\ldots,t_{n-1})$ be vector space spanned by the first $n-1$ of these. Let $$t^i=(t_1^i,\ldots,t_{n-1}^i),0\leq t^i_1< \cdots < t^i_{n-1}\leq 1$$ be a sequence such that $t^i_{n-1}\to 0$ as $i\to \infty$. Since the space of all vector hyperplanes in $\mathbf{R}^n$ is compact, we can assume the sequence $L(t^i)$ has a limit $L$.

Claim: for any $s,t$ such that $0< s < t\leq 1$ the hyperplane $L$ does not separate $F'(s)$ and $F'(t)$.

Proof of the claim: if $L$ does, then for all sufficiently large $i$ the hyperplane $L(t^i)$ also separates $F'(s)$ and $F'(t)$. Choose $i$ so that moreover $t^i_{n-1} < s$. Then the determinants of the matrices $(F'(t^i_1),\ldots, F'(t^i_{n-1}),F'(s))$ and $(F'(t^i_1),\ldots, F'(t^i_{n-1}),F'(t))$ have different signs. This is impossible, since $F'$ is continuous and the determinant is never zero. Claim is proven.

Now one of the two things can happen: either all $F'(t),0 \leq t\leq 1$ are in $L$, in which case $F'(t_1),\ldots, F'(t_n)$ are linearly dependent for all $t_1,\ldots, t_n$, or there is a $t$ such that for $l(F'(t))\neq 0$ where $l$ is a linear equation defining $L$. Say, $l(F'(t)) > 0$. Then $l(F(0)) < l(F(1))$, so we can't have $F(0)=F(1)$.

upd: here is how one can take care of the case when $F'$ is not assumed continuous. Basically, the only thing that changes is the proof of the claim; the claim itself remains the same except that we assume $t < 1$. Choose $i$ as above and set $g(x),s\leq x\leq t$ to be the determinant of $(F'(t^i_1),\ldots,F'(t^i_{n-1}),F(x))$. This function is differentiable and we have $g'(x)=det(F'(t^i_1),\ldots,F'(t^i_{n-1}),F'(x))$. So $g'(s)$ and $g'(t)$ have different signs. The claim follows now from the following statement, which is a consequence of the classical Rolle's theorem: if $f:[a,b]\to\mathbf{R}$ is differentiable at each point of $[a,b]$ and $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$ have different signs, then there is an $x\in (a,b)$ such that $f'(x)=0$.

Then we deduce from the claim that all $F'(t),0 < t < 1$ are in the same half-space with respect to $L$. This suffices.

Comment: This is a nice proof.  Does L agree with something like an osculating hyperplane (from the right, perhaps?) to the curve at t=0?  

Comment: jc -- $L$ is the osculating plane, that is, if enough derivatives exist and are linearly independent.

Answer (score 14):

It is more natural to ask $0\in\mathop{Conv}\{f'(t_i)\}$.

Clearly $0\in\mathop{Conv}f'([a,b])$, thus from Carathéodory's theorem we get $n+1$ points.
Further, we can remove two points and exchange them to one. The later follows easeely if $f'$ is continuous, otherwise it is a bit of work...

Comment: Your wonderful 1-paragraph explanation is equivalent to, but so much cleaner and concise than our effort, I must say wow!

Comment: That's really slick!

Comment: I don´t understand why $0$ is in the convex hull of $f'([a,b])$. The function could very well be linear and non-constant...

Comment: @Mariano: The function was assumed to have the same value at both end points.

Answer (score 7):

Let's add a bit of Anton Petrunin's answer into algori's: namely, I'm going to spell out the 'little  bit of work' from Anton's answer, which is a version of algori's Claim. I am not proving the stronger statement made by Anton though, only the original statement. (This was supposed to be a comment: my attempt to write algori's proof without taking limits, but it turned out to be too long for comments.)

Claim 1 (Petrunin): $0\in Conv(f'(a,b))$.

Proof: Otherwise there is a hyperplane separating $0$ from the convex hull.

By Caratheodory's Theorem, we get 
$$a < t_1 < \dots < t_{n+1} < b$$ such that 
$$0\in Conv(f'(t_1),\dots,f'(t_{n+1}).$$

Claim 2 (algori): There is $s\in[t_n,t_{n+1}]$ such that 
$$0\in Span(f'(t_1),\dots,f'(t_{n-1}),f'(s)).$$

Proof: Set $$l(x)=\det(f'(t_1),\dots,f'(t_n),f(x)).$$ The condition on $s$ is that $l'(s)=0$. By Claim 1, either $$0\in Conv(f'(t_1),\dots,f'(t_{n-1}))$$ (in which case the claim is obvious) or $0$ lies between $l'(t_n)$ and $l'(t_{n-1})$. In the latter case, such $s$ exists by the usual Rolle's theorem.

Answer (score 4):

This is the corrected proof of the satement in the case when $F'$ is supposed to be continuous. We also assume that $F'$ never vanishes, othevise the statement is obviuous. The first four comments below are about previous versions of my proof, which were not correct. So first 4 comments  are not relevant anymore to this answer (really sorry for that).

I will use slightly modified reasoning of Ilya (please read his answer. His idea is that we conisder the curve $\frac{F'}{|F'|}$ in the unit $S^{n-1}$). 
Then we need to prove a little lemma.

Lemma. Consider a continous curve $C$ on a sphere $S^{n-1}$ that doesn't lie inside any half-sphere parametrised by an inteval $[0,1]$. Prove that there exists an equator that intersects the curve for at least $n$ different values of the parameter.

Proof. The center of the sphere belongs to the convex hull of $C$ by the assumption of the lemma. This means that there are $n+1$ or less points on $C$ such that the simplex with vertices in these points contains the centre $0$ of the sphere.  If the number of points is less than $n+1$, we are done. Suppose that the number of points is in fact $n+1$ and they are linearly inependent. We call the points $x(t_1),...,x(t_{n+1})$ where $t_i$ are odered for. Consider now the hyperplane $H$ generated by points $x(t_1),...,x(t_{n-1})$ and the center of the sphere. $H$ cuts $S^{n-1}$ in two halves. Since by constructions the convex hull of $x(t_i)$ contains $0$, the points $x(t_n), x(t_{n+1})$ are in different half spaces with respect to the plane. So  this plane intersects the part of curve C contained between $t_n$, $t_{n+1}$ in some point $x(t_n')$. The lemma is proved.

Comment: The function $F$ can very well be constant... and then $0$ will not be in the convex hull the the curve.

Comment: @Dmitri, The simplex you're talking about will have $n+1$ vertices, while the problem is to show that there is a simplex with $n$ vertices.

Comment: I don't understand what you are proving here.  Can you explain say in the case n=2?  Also where are you using the derivative of F?

Comment: What has to be independent is a set of $n$ values of the *derivative*.

Comment: Please, before it's too late, just return back your old text and post a new answer with the new text! Otherwise, people will not understand what the comments refer to!

Comment: Anyway, "So this plane intersects the part of curve C contained between tn, tn+1 in some point x(t0n)" – it's possible that the intersection point is actually one of $t_1, \dots, t_{n-1}$.

Comment: No - he is considering the arc of $C$ which doesn't contain these points. I think this is why he says that the $t_i$ should be ordered.

Comment: You are right, but we are allowd to count with mulitplicities.

Comment: @Dmitri,  we can't count with mulitplicities. But now it appears to me you proved the lemma.

Comment: The same argument works without continuity, instead you use that $f'(x)$ belongs to closure of $Conv f'([x,y]$.

Comment: Ilya, sorry for confusion from my part. I mean, that if a curve passes trough one point twice (for different values of parameter), like what you suggested, then this point can be counted twice for the purpose of the statement that we want to prove...

Comment: Mm.. yeah, in a sense. I mean, if a curve self-intersects, this trivially solves the original problem (two copies of a vector are always linearly dependent). Congratulations!

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen such an interesting analysis problem :) Here is my current state, which I post because I like this form in itself and because I hope somebody finishes it.

We can reformulate what we want to prove as follows, by taking the direction of $F'(t)$:

> Consider a smooth curve on a sphere $S^{n-1}$ that doesn't lie inside any half-sphere. Prove that there exists an equator that intersects the curve in at least $n$ points.

(Note that an there is $n-1$-dimensional family of equators.)

Now suppose there were a contradictory curve. I'm currently thinking about shrinking it: if we can do it keeping the offending properties (using that there are no $n$-intersecting equators) then we'll arrive to contradiction since once the curve is small it's definitely inside half-circle.

Comment: Ilya, I corrected my previous post. This is uses the same idea as yours. I think, this time I prove your lemma. So it gives the proof of the statement if we suppose $F'$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The following solution is incomplete. We need to make sure that if $F^{\prime}\left(t\right)$, $F^{\prime\prime}\left(t\right)$, ..., $F^{\left(n-1\right)}\left(t\right)$ are linearly dependent vectors for every $t$, then the coordinate functions of $F^{\prime}$ are linearly dependent on a sufficiently small interval. This follows from Wronskian considerations if the coordinate functions of $F^{\prime}$ are sufficiently nice (i. e., locally real-analytic), so this solves the problem for this nice class of functions, but I can't use this ansatz further.

"SOLUTION".

IMPORTANT: I consider $F$ to be a map from $S^1$ to $\mathbb R^n$, because a map from an interval with equal values at the ends is the same as a map from the circle. I will assume continuity of $F^{\prime}$ (yes, this includes the two endpoints of the interval which I have glued together). So I don't claim I have 100% solved the original problem.

I will say that an $n$-tuple of distinct points $\left(t_1,t_2,...,t_n\right)\in \left(S^1\right)^n$ is in counterclockwise position if there is an orientation-preserving map $\Phi:S^1\to \left[0,1\right]$, continuous except at one point, such that $\Phi\left(t_1\right)<\Phi\left(t_2\right)<...<\Phi\left(t_n\right)$. I need the following intuitively obvious fact:

(1) If an $n$-tuple of distinct points $\left(t_1,t_2,...,t_n\right)\in \left(S^1\right)^n$ is in counterclockwise position, and an $n$-tuple of distinct points $\left(s_1,s_2,...,s_n\right)\in \left(S^1\right)^n$ is in counterclockwise position as well, then there exists a smooth way to move the points $t_1$, $t_2$, ..., $t_n$ along $S^1$ such that they occupy the places of $s_1$, $s_2$, ..., $s_n$ at the end, and such that they stay distinct at any time during the process.

I could formalize this if anyone asks me to.

As a consequence of (1) and the intermediate value theorem (the usual one, for functions $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$), we have:

(2) If an $n$-tuple of distinct points $\left(t_1,t_2,...,t_n\right)\in \left(S^1\right)^n$ is in counterclockwise position, and an $n$-tuple of distinct points $\left(s_1,s_2,...,s_n\right)\in \left(S^1\right)^n$ is in counterclockwise position as well, and $R:\left(S^1\right)^n\to \mathbb R$ is a continuous map that never takes the value $0$ on $n$-tuples of distinct points, then the reals $R\left(t_1,t_2,...,t_n\right)$ and $R\left(s_1,s_2,...,s_n\right)$ have the same sign.

In other words,

(3) If $R:\left(S^1\right)^n\to \mathbb R$ is a continuous map that never takes the value $0$ on $n$-tuples of distinct points, then for any $n$-tuple of distinct points $\left(t_1,t_2,...,t_n\right)\in \left(S^1\right)^n$ in counterclockwise position, the real $R\left(t_1,t_2,...,t_n\right)$ has the same sign.

Now, let's solve the problem: Assume that the assertion is wrong, and thus $F^{\prime}\left(t_1\right)$, $F^{\prime}\left(t_2\right)$, ..., $F^{\prime}\left(t_n\right)$ are linearly independent for any $n$-tuple of distinct points $\left(t_1,t_2,...,t_n\right)\in \left(S^1\right)^n$. Then, applying (3) to the continuous map

$R:\left(S^1\right)^n\to \mathbb R,$
$\left(t_1,t_2,...,t_n\right)\mapsto \det\left(F^{\prime}\left(t_1\right),F^{\prime}\left(t_2\right),...,F^{\prime}\left(t_n\right)\right)$,

we obtain that:

(4) For any $n$-tuple of distinct points $\left(t_1,t_2,...,t_n\right)\in \left(S^1\right)^n$ in counterclockwise position, the real $\det\left(F^{\prime}\left(t_1\right),F^{\prime}\left(t_2\right),...,F^{\prime}\left(t_n\right)\right)$ has the same sign.

Let's WLOG say that it is positive all the time (if its negative, just rewrite the proof with negative instead of positive...), i. e. we have:

(5) For any $n$-tuple of distinct points $\left(t_1,t_2,...,t_n\right)\in \left(S^1\right)^n$ in counterclockwise position, the real $\det\left(F^{\prime}\left(t_1\right),F^{\prime}\left(t_2\right),...,F^{\prime}\left(t_n\right)\right)$ is positive.

Now, move $t_2$, $t_3$, ..., $t_{n-1}$ (not $t_n$) closer and closer to $t_1$ (while keeping the counterclockwise position, of course), while keeping $t_1$ and $t_n$ fixed. Then, $\det\left(F^{\prime}\left(t_1\right),F^{\prime}\left(t_2\right),...,F^{\prime}\left(t_n\right)\right)$ tends to $\det\left(F^{\prime}\left(t_1\right),F^{\prime\prime}\left(t_1\right),...,F^{\left(n-1\right)}\left(t_1\right),F^{\prime}\left(t_n\right)\right)$. So, we get:

(5) For any pair of distinct points $\left(t_1,t_n\right)\in \left(S^1\right)^2$ in counterclockwise position, the real $\det\left(F^{\prime}\left(t_1\right),F^{\prime\prime}\left(t_1\right),...,F^{\left(n-1\right)}\left(t_1\right),F^{\prime}\left(t_n\right)\right)$ is nonnegative.

Notice how "positive" became "nonnegative" due to the limiting process (the limit of positive reals needs not be positive, but is always nonnegative).

Now, any pair of distinct points on $S^1$ is in counterclockwise position (and in clockwise position, too), so (5) can be simply rewritten as follows:

(6) For any pair of distinct points $\left(t,s\right)\in \left(S^1\right)^2$, the real $\det\left(F^{\prime}\left(t\right),F^{\prime\prime}\left(t\right),...,F^{\left(n-1\right)}\left(t\right),F^{\prime}\left(s\right)\right)$ is nonnegative.

We can drop the "distinct" in (6), as well, because for $s=t$, the real is simply $0$. So we have:

(7) For any pair of points $\left(t,s\right)\in \left(S^1\right)^2$, the real $\det\left(F^{\prime}\left(t\right),F^{\prime\prime}\left(t\right),...,F^{\left(n-1\right)}\left(t\right),F^{\prime}\left(s\right)\right)$ is nonnegative.

But if we fix $t$ and integrate $\det\left(F^{\prime}\left(t\right),F^{\prime\prime}\left(t\right),...,F^{\left(n-1\right)}\left(t\right),F^{\prime}\left(s\right)\right)$ over $s\in S^1$, we must get zero (because $\det\left(F^{\prime}\left(t\right),F^{\prime\prime}\left(t\right),...,F^{\left(n-1\right)}\left(t\right),F^{\prime}\left(s\right)\right)$ is linear in $F^{\prime}\left(s\right)$, and the integral of $F^{\prime}\left(s\right)$ over $S^1$ is zero). The integral of a continuous nonnegative function is zero only if the function itself is identically zero. Thus, $\det\left(F^{\prime}\left(t\right),F^{\prime\prime}\left(t\right),...,F^{\left(n-1\right)}\left(t\right),F^{\prime}\left(s\right)\right)$ for all $s\in S^1$. This means that $F^{\prime}\left(s\right)$ lies in a fixed hyperplane for all $s\in S^1$. Now, taking ANY $n$ points $t_1$, $t_2$, ..., $t_n$ on $S^1$, we get linearly dependent vectors $F^{\prime}\left(t_1\right)$, $F^{\prime}\left(t_2\right)$, ..., $F^{\prime}\left(t_n\right)$, and this is of course a contradiction!

Or do we?

Answer (score 1):

What is missing in the original solution is the following observation: If $F([a,t^\ast])$ does not lie a hyperplane, then we can find $\epsilon>0$ such that the extremum of $|P\circ F|$ on any one-dimensional projection $P$ orthogonal to $F(t^\ast)-F(a)$ does not occur on $(t^\ast-\epsilon,t^\ast]$.  Similarly for $[t^\ast,a]$.

With this, you just pick $n-2$ points on $(t^\ast-\epsilon,t^\ast+\epsilon)$.  We may assume that the space spanned by $F'$ at each of these points is $n-1$-dimensional and does not contain the vector $F(t^\ast)-F(a)$ (if it necessarily does, then adding one additional point makes the collection linearly dependent).  Now throw in $F(t^\ast)-F(a)$ to obtain a hyperplane $L$ and take an orthogonal projection to obtain an extreme point on each side of $t^\ast$.  Its derivative is zero, and it doesn't lie in the original collection by the remark.